# Meraki API connection refused from test server

Tags: docker, meraki-api

I have a java application and it can successfully connect to **api.meraki.com** in my local machine but when I deploy my java application to the test server,
the application which lives in a docker container can not connect to **api.meraki.com**.

In the host machine, I can also curl the **api.meraki.com** but inside my docker container (docker exec -it xxx /bin/bash), I can't curl as it gives a connection refused error.

I tried to use a new API key to test server but it is still giving connection refused error. I also tried to allow my test server from Meraki dashboard but no success.

Any ideas that what is the problem and the solution?

edit: i run container with
`docker run -dit -p 9078:8080 -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger,preprod" --name abc -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -v /etc/hosts:/tmp/hosts example.com.com:5000/abc:v1.12.5`

and in my container when i run `getent hosts api.meraki.com` resolves dns as:

```
209.206.57.71   mun211.meraki.com api.meraki.com emea.api.meraki.com n23.meraki.com
```

Comment: Can you provide the `docker run` or the `docker-compose` that you are using to launch the container? Also a `docker ps` for your container could be helpful.

Comment: also, a `nslookup api.meraki.com` inside the container to see how is that name resolved.

Comment: @NeoAnderson i edited the question for your questions

Answer (score 0):

test server was behind proxy and it was not configured, configuring both container and the application resolved the problem. (i think the application is connecting other service by bypassing the proxy.